# Can I watch Hellraiser Judgement without watching the previous installments?

Tags: suggested-order, hellraiser, hellraiser-judgment

I was wondering if it was something like *Star Wars* or the *Saw* series where events are interrelated.

So, can I watch *Hellraiser: Judgment* without watching the previous installments?

Comment: There's not too much in those movies that have interlocking stories besides the first two, if I remember correctly.  The main thing that you need to know is the importance of the puzzle box.  But, the movies do a fairly good job of bringing you up to date on any past story lines in each movie.  I have not seen the newest one that you're referring to, so I can't give you a definite answer on that.  Good luck :)